# Comparator for vector<pair<int,int>>

Tags: c++, vector, stl, comparator, std-pair

```
vector<pair<int,int> > v;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    cin>>b>>c;
    v.push_back(make_pair(b,c));
}
sort(v.begin(),v.end());
```

Is it possible to write a comparator for the sort function such that `v[i].first` is sorted in increasing order and for similar values of `v[i].first`, `v[i].second` is sorted in decreasing order?
like:-
i/p:

```
 13 10  
 44 15  
 13 15  
 13 99  
  6 45
```

o/p:

```
 6 45  
 13 99  
 13 15  
 13 10  
 44 15
```

Comment: Is this C++? Please add a tag specifying what language you're using.

Comment: Yes, it is possible and quite trivial. You just need to write a suitable comparison function and pass it to `std::sort`.

Comment: @TomZych: sorry for that yes it is C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Having trouble in writing the comparator, can u help me about how can i write a comparator for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it's easy enough.

All you need to do is write a function with this signature:

```
bool f(std::pair<int, int> lhs, std::pair<int, int> rhs);
```

The function should return `true` if and only if `lhs < rhs`

So, by your criteria, `lhs` is smaller than `rhs` if:

- `lhs.first < rhs.first`,
- *or* `lhs.first == rhs.first && lhs.second > rhs.second`

So, basically just put those together, and you get:

```
bool mycomparer(std::pair<int, int> lhs, std::pair<int, int> rhs) {
    if (lhs.first < rhs.first) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (lhs.first == rhs.first && lhs.second > rhs.second) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This could be written much more compactly, but I wanted to keep it simple and readable to get the point across. :)

Comment: you should encourage using functors.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a compact comparison function object that does what you want: (*uses C++11 features*)

```
struct Shivam {
    typedef std::pair<int, int> const& param_type;
    bool operator()(param_type lhs, param_type rhs) const {
        return std::tie(lhs.first, rhs.second) < std::tie(rhs.first, lhs.second);
    };
};
```

And use it like this:

```
std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), Shivam{});
```